# Get a list of pages a user has in Facebook with Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I expected to find some thing like this in the graph api:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/pages
```

Could not find anything like that.

Is it possible to get a list of pages a user has/is admin of?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/user/accounts

Authorize with `manage_pages` and call `/me/accounts` to get a list of all the managed Pages.

Comment: thank you, it did it) one more question if you don't mind. I see you have been a member here for a long time. Why was my question downvoted a couple of times? is it because I included django and python in tags?

Comment: no, it´s most likely because you did not specify what you have tried so far. your question looks like you did not take a look at the official docs first. always do some research before asking. (google, stackoverflow, facebook docs, ...)

Comment: @JohnyStark Your question is very broad, and lacks own research effort. Instead of *expecting* something, you could always check in the relevant docs first, before posting a question. Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask Also, using tags which do not relate to your question doesn't make it better.

Comment: @Tobi and luschn, thank you for your advice. I actually did my research first, read the docs and threads here in SO but did not mention. I will do that next time after I am unbanned :) thanks again